# Missing resource exception can't find resource for bundle sun.security.util.Resources, key PKCS11 Token[Provider] Password

Tags: keystore, pkcs#11

I trying to load the pkcs11 keystore using sunjava jdk 7 update 11 on windows 2008  64bit machine.the problem iam facing is i was able to get the keystore instance with

```
Keystore ks = Keystore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
```

but when i say

```
keystore.load(null, "pwdstring".toCharArray[])
```

at this line iam facing an error saying , Please find the stacktrace

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle sun.security.util.Resources, key PKCS11 Token [providerName] Password: 
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:393)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:353)
    at sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getString(ResourcesMgr.java:52)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1084)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:874)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:764)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at HSM_TokenSunjava.main(HSM_TokenSunjava.java:37)
```

And one more thing with same code and same PKCS11 token i was able to run on my machine windows 64bit i dont understand what wrong with windows 2008 machine.

Kindly help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and verified that the Resource was changed from `"PKCS11 Token [providerName] Password:"`  to `"PKCS11.Token.providerName.Password."` so `SUNPKCS11` call to `"PKCS11 Token [providerName] Password: "`  must be changed to new value.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Changing JDK version to JDK6 solved my problem.